# How to create a list of email addresses from ldapsearch result for further processing?

Tags: ldap, output, text-formatting

For an automated mailing and to notify user, respective members of a specific group, I am looking for commands or a single command line which provides a list of email addresses and which can be used further.

Currently I am able to look up the directory in a way like:

```
ldapsearch -h dc.example.com -p 389 -D "EXAMPLE\admin" -x -w "password" -b "DC=example,DC=com" -s sub "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=CN=Developers,OU=Role_Groups,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com))" mail \
| grep "mail:" \
| cut -d " " -f 2
```

This gives me the email addresses of all group members condensed, but not in the format for further processing I were looking for.

```
admin@example.com
developer@example.com
user@example.com
...
```

How to get the results in one line i.e. comma or semicolon separated?

```
admin@example.com;developer@example.com;user@example.com;...
```

[Replacing newlines with commas using `tr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022935/how-to-replace-newlines-with-commas-using-tr) or `sed` wasn't working (for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I've found the [`paste` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paste). So adding

```
| paste -sd ";"
```

made it working in the way I was looking for. The final command line I'am using now is

```
ldapsearch -h dc.example.com -p 389 -D "EXAMPLE\admin" -x -w "password" -b "DC=example,DC=com" -s sub "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=CN=Developers,OU=Role_Groups,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com))" mail \
| grep "mail:" \
| cut -d " " -f 2 \
| paste -sd ";"
```